# How to count the number of mutual link between turtles in netlogo?

Tags: netlogo

I have a network of turtles connected by links in Netlogo an I'm struggling to find a way to calculate the number of mutual links between turtles (ie if I randomly choose two turtles, how many of each of their links are connecting them to the same turtles?). Has anyone had luck with this?

Comment: sounds more like transitivity than mutuality... you are in looking for mutual neighbors, not mutual links...

Answer (score 3):

With undirected links:

```
count ([link-neighbors] of turtle 0) with [member? turtle 1 link-neighbors]
```